# request to a port of a centos server and write log

Tags: linux, iptables

excuse me, maybe you think my question is stupid, but I heard there is a port (or many ports) on `centos` that if a client send request to that,and the request fails for any reason (like IP blocking from server), the server write a line to a log file.
Im asking that, because recently I have been under DDos attack and my `direct admin` blocked attacker IP, but he continued sending request and my server's memory became full (I had 96% full memory unfortunately ) .
so , anyone knows anything  about that? or what port it is ?

Comment: There is no port but you can use *iptables* with a default LOG target option.

Comment: would you explain a little more? @deagh

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LOG target within iptables to log all packets to log all incoming packets just use

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
```

Comment: where is the log file stored?

Comment: This depends on your log daemon mostly the target should be 'syslog'